# SQLite and performance issue with SELECT total(value)

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite

Hello and a happy new year,

we are still struggling with our simulation application. Especially with using SQLite as a 'real time' look up table for simulation data while running.

Let me show you the table design first:
[SQLfiddle - Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d6750/1)

Here you can see a table 'testtable' with:

1. 'id' (integer): as the primary key
2. 'time_abs' (integer): represents a time stamp associated with the simulation clock
3. 'r_m' (double): stands for 'mass rate' (unit is kg/s e.g.) of some flow
4. 'T_r' (double): stands for 'temperature of mass flow'
5. 'type'(varchar): stands for the kind of the mass flow (e.g. water)
6. 'x0' (varchar): represents the departure of the mass flow (e.g. vessel #1)
7. 'x1' (varchar): represents the destination of the mass flow (e.g. vessel #2)

(Actually there are some more chemical and physical attributes written into this table)

The simulation creates those data and it is written with Java methods into the database, which works pretty good (a few 10k/s possible).

**The issue is:**

While the simulation is running the simulation engine sometime needs certain information like 
"***What is the total mass in vessel1 at time 14?***" 
We receive this information with a query like this:

---

`SELECT total(r_m) FROM testtable WHERE time_abs<=14 AND x1='vessel2') - (SELECT total(r_m) FROM testtable WHERE time_abs<=14 AND x0='vessel2');` (***which is: adding all income rates and substracting all outcome rates at one local point***)

---

Which works fine at the beginning. But in the end we have about 8 to 10 million rows in this table and the performance drops a lot. E.g. this query almost take 6 seconds (3-4 seconds with SQLite mangaer in firefox).

Also in the end we would like to plot total mass over a period of 1000 time units (time_abs) with this query which will need about 1000*6 seconds. Obviously to much.

So the question is, what can we do to significantly increase the performance?

Comment: you only need the last 14 timestamp?

Comment: No all 'time_abs' less than 'search time'. Also the timestamp 'time_abs' is not unique because of concurrent processes. So within the query example one is not able to say how many timestamps are queried, as the number of concurrent processes is variable.

Comment: (by "concurrent processes" I mean processes within the simulated process not concurrently accessing SQLite, just for clarification)

Comment: How many "vessels" do you have?

Comment: Not a constant value as this is one of the simulation inputs. But to give you a magnitude I would say about 200.

Comment: do the simulation need older mass data, like after time_abs<=14 it will need time_abs<=2?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. Also the simulation reporting system needs those 'historical'data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it help you, if you use one or more additional field(s), where you update/increment the wanted value

```
eg. total_rm  or total_diff
```

Then you do not need total(), but you can access the value directly with

```
SELECT total_rm FROM testtable WHERE time_abs=14 AND x1='vessel2')
```

Of course you should create an index over time_abs.

Comment: So this query is the same like "SELECT r_m from testtable WHERE time_abs=14 AND x1='vessel2'", right? Just to check the select-performance I tried this query on a 10 million row table and it takes about 4-5 seconds. As far as I know, the problem here is that I do not use a primary key. Both 'time_abs' and 'x1' are not unique. For instance if I query with the addon "where id=15" (e.g.) it takes 1 ms only.

Comment: and what hinders you to create an index over time_abs?

Comment: there is no need, that the index has to be unique. It just shortens the access, instead of reading all rows serially, the db program just reads first the index and then directly the wanteds row(s)

Comment: thank you. I am answering this late because I have tried to implement your suggestion. There is one pitfall. Or at leat I am not able to get this SQL command as Java Batch run: "INSERT INTO testtable (r_m) VALUES(5+(SELECT r_m FROM testtable ORDER BY r_m DESC LIMIT 1));"     <--- What I want to do is to increment the  r_m_total in '5'-steps (like 0,5,10,15,20,...). If I submit this query manually it works fine, but within a Batch-statement it just inserts '5, 5, 5,...'. Do you have any idea?

Comment: if your db reads the first value (= 0) because of LIMIT 1 then this is understandable. Maybe you should either keep your last writtten r_m value in memory, or use and increment a SQL variable or just use 5 + max(r_m) in your subselect, but without the LIMIT clause. It all depends how your optimizer works and how your indices look like.

Comment: You could even use an additional table with just one row and one field  last_rm a.s.o.. I would definitely hold my last_rm in memory.

Comment: Are you sure you meant r_m and not time_abs?

Comment: Okay this a again a very good idea, thank you. Another issue is: suppose we have to incoming flows: flow#1 starts at time 10 and ends at time 100. Therefore data will be stored from time 10 to 100. Flow#2 starts at time 30 and ends at time 40. The issue is, if we query 'SELECT mass_total... WHERE time_abs=100' flow#2 will not be included since the column 'mass_total' @ time_abs=100 is not update via flow#2-data input. Should we try a trigger? But how fast can a trigger possibly be to update a whole column over million of rows? Is it worth trying?

Comment: w.r.t. to your comment above. You mean 'ORDER BY time_abs'? I tried this right now: "INSERT INTO testtable (time_abs, r_m) VALUES(?, 5+(SELECT r_m FROM testtable WHERE time_abs <=? ORDER BY r_m DeSC LIMIT 1));" (prepared statement), whichs works fine. I over-simplified it, as I thought "ORDER BY r_m...LIMIT 1" will automatically keep the last (biggest) r_m in memory.

Comment: even if there is no change in mass_total or whatever, you should keep the last value in the total_ fields of new rows

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44900/discussion-between-sqlab-and-stefan-h)

Answer (score 1):

Possibilities:

1. Pre-calculate your required result. So, when you do the raw data insert, update a row in a "totals" table. Each row simulates your query, updating based on time_abs and vessel. So the table might have column:

   time_abs, vessel, running_total

   You update running_total with the new value based on time_abs and vessel
2. Off-load the raw data processing to a more capable server. So on each n inserts of raw data, upload that data to an more capable server using web services. Have that machine calculate your results in real time. Once data insert is complete (end of the data gathering) your results, in theory, are ready for retrieving back onto the Android (again via web services or similar).

Comment: Wrt to option 1: I think this is just like what sqlab answered but with another table (please correct me if I am wrong here). No use of a primary key here also? Wrt to option 2: we are not able to use further hardware as the simulation application should be stand-alone and for free.

Comment: They key thing is is "pre-calculate" the result (via a totals concept) as your go. Implement based on "best practice".

Comment: Yeah I think you and sqlab are definitly right. The total(xyz)-concept will not work.

Answer (score 1):

This particular query can be made more efficient with the following indexes:

```sql
CREATE INDEX i_ir ON testtable(x1, time_abs, r_m);
CREATE INDEX i_or ON testtable(x0, time_abs, r_m);
```

Comment: Thank you. It is indeed a lot faster but still not fast enough. To SELECT total(r_m) sillt takes >>1 second.

Comment: You said the original without indexes took 3-6 seconds. How much faster? (Anyway, if millions of records match, nothing can be done except precomputing some aggregate values.)

Comment: ~1.5-3 seconds. It is definitly much faster but still not enough. Thank you anyway, I always appreciate your answers. So, we try to implement a good solution with precomputing the results right now.